# Calculate Seconds between two LocalDates in Java

Tags: java, time, localdate

i am trying to calculate seconds between two LocalDates.
Now this is actually giving me a hard time as this code snippet is
not working that well:

```
long seconds = lastRefreshPoint.until(systemTime, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

This gives me the Exception:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Minutes
```

I cant really find any other way to do this on the Internet.
It would be nice if you could help me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the declaration and instantiation of `lastRefreshPoint`?

Comment: How are you creating `lastRefreshPoint`?

Comment: This does not make any sense since a calendar date does not know anything about hours, minutes or seconds. The lowest supported unit must be the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here my comment as answer together with some details about the reasons of the behaviour observed.

**Summarizing:**

This does not make any sense since a calendar date does not know anything about hours, minutes or seconds. The lowest supported unit must be the day. See also the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isSupported-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) of Java-8-class `LocalDate`:

> If the unit is a ChronoUnit then the query is implemented here. The
>   supported units are:  •DAYS  •WEEKS  •MONTHS  •YEARS  •DECADES 
>   •CENTURIES  •MILLENNIA  •ERAS  All other ChronoUnit instances will
>   return false.

**Reasons:**

While someone can imagine to implement the difference in seconds between two connecting days as 86400 seconds (ignoring zone effects or leap seconds), it would not be a good idea. If the API designers had decided to support the between-arithmetic then they should also have decided to support adding of seconds to a date. But here the problem starts:

date + 86400 secs = next date

But what is date + 123 secs???

**The support for units more precise than a day in the class `LocalDate` would cause inconsistencies which cannot be cured.**

Answer (score 2):

The Answer by Hochschild is correct and should be accepted.

## `LocalDate::atStartOfDay`

To make a date-time value from your date-only value, go with the first moment of the day. Doing that requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date can vary around the globe by zone.

Do not assume the day starts at time `00:00:00`.  Because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time, the day may begin at a time such as `01:00:00`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = myLocalDate.atStartOfDay( z );
```

Then proceed with calculating elapsed time.

```
Duration d = Duration.of( zdtStart , zdtStop );
long seconds = d.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this myself as this was posted as a comment and not as an answer:

> This does not make any sense since a calendar date does not know
> anything about hours, minutes or seconds. The lowest supported unit
> must be the day.
>
> -- Meno Hochschild

This pretty much hits the point.

Thanks a lot, Meno Hochschild

Comment: Note that Meno has now [posted an expanded answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913130/calculate-seconds-between-two-localdates-in-java/40913844#40913844)